# Android - Como identificar exceções lançadas em celulares?

Tags: android

Quando é lançada uma exception não tratada o aplicativo é fechado (ex: NullPointerException), até ai está tudo bem quando você está testando o aplicativo pela IDE, mas quando você gera um apk e quer que seus amigos testem o aplicativo para você, quando é gerado uma exceção, como identificar o erro?

Eu gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de identificar todas as exceções lançadas no Android para exibir um AlertDialog do tipo:
"Exceção lançada e o app será fechado: **java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example...** " ou uma solução semelhante tal como  salvar todos os logs do aplicativo num documento de texto, etc.

Obrigado :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics?utm_campaign=fabric-marketing&utm_medium=natural) agrega os erros que ocorrem em todos os aparelhos em uma interface Web. É bastante utilizado pra isso. No painel do Google Play você também tem acesso aos relatórios enviados por usuários do seu aplicativo que baixaram ele pelo Google Play.

Comment: Excelente sugestão, muito obrigado, já comecei a usar e adorei, além disso contém vários outros recursos, uma boa interface e é totalmente gratuito!